# CSS animation below elements and centered vertically

Tags: html, css, animation

I want to achieve the following:

- cloud1 div to be above welcome-section div and to move below the other children elements without affecting the position of the other children elements FROM A Z-AXIS PERSPECTIVE **- see attached image of what I want to achieve**.
- cloud1 to be in the center of welcome-section FROM A Y AXIS PERSPECTIVE.

I only achieved this after working a lot on it but cannot make as I mentioned above - I added a demo at the end.

```
<div class="welcome-section">
  <div id="cloud1"></div>
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">THE BEST IS YET TO COME</h1>
    <h2 style="text-align: center;" fxFlexOffset="50px">USE IT TO DO ANYTHING</h2>
    <button mat-raised-button fxFlexOffset="25px">TRY IT FOR FREE</button>
    <img class="recycle-image" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-jewels-icon-set/512/0000_Refresh.png" alt="Computer Hope" fxFlexOffset="25px">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#cloud1{
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background:#cb239e;
  margin:140px 0 0 0;
  border-radius:50px;
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-400px);
  transform:translateX(-400px);
  -webkit-animation: move 7s linear infinite;
  animation: move 7s linear infinite ;
  display:block-inline;
  position: relative;

}
#cloud1:before{
  content:"";
  position: relative;
  width:180px;
  height:180px;
  background:#cb239e;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:-100px 0 0 20px;

}
#cloud1:after{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
  background:#cb239e;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:-60px 0 0 165px;

}
```

I also made a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-up8opv).

The output of what I want to achieve:
[image]
Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit confusing. You need cloud1 to be at the top or in the centre? Or animate from top to center? Have you tried using translateY?

Comment: @PankajPhartiyal, added extra explanation and sample of desired result.

Comment: As I said you need to have a Y translate as well. Second argument in `translate()` value is the Y translation. So, convert all instances of `transform: translateX(Xpx);` to `transform: translate(Xpx, 160px);`. Adjust `160px` as per your requirement. You also have to play with `z-index` of the content and the cloud. I want you to try it out yourself first, maybe then I'll share the solution with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
 p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.welcome-section {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  height: auto;
  background: #3f51b5;
  background-size: auto auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.welcome-section h1,
.welcome-section h2,
.welcome-section button,
.welcome-section img{
  z-index: 1;
}
#cloud1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background:#cb239e;
  margin:140px 0 0 0;
  border-radius:50px;
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-400px);
  transform:translateX(-400px);
  -webkit-animation: move 7s linear infinite;
  animation: move 7s linear infinite ;
  display: flex;
  // overflow-x: auto;
  z-index: 0;
}
#cloud1:before{
  content:"";
  position: relative;
  width:180px;
  height:180px;
  background:#cb239e;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:-100px 0 0 20px;

}
#cloud1:after{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
  background:#cb239e;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin:-60px 0 0 165px;

}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-340px);opacity:0;}
  20%{opacity:1;}
  90%{opacity:1;}
  100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(1650px);opacity:0;}
}
@keyframes move {
  0%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-340px);opacity:0;}
  20%{opacity:1;}
  90%{opacity:1;}
  100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(1650px);opacity:0;}
}

img.recycle-image {
  width: 250px;
}
```